# What is the correct way to wire 2 three way switches with a single pole switch when the power line is entering in the middle of the circuit?

Tags: wiring, switch, multiway-switch

I originally asked this over on electronics.stackexchange.com, but they don't seem to have the skills to figure out the correct way to wire this situation. Someone suggested I post it here instead.

[image]

Above is the way it is currently wired. What I am looking for is guidance on the correct way to wire it. The main issue seems to be that the power line is coming into the gang box on the right. There wouldn't be an issue if there was a power line coming into the gang box on the left and a separate power line coming into the gang box on the right, but that isn't what I have. Is there a way to wire this up correctly, or do I need to run a new power line from the panel to the gang box on the left? That would be... unfortunate since it is a run of about 70 feet and I'd have to go through walls.

Comment: On StackExchange, instead of double posting, you should hit "Flag... moderator... "please move to (new stack here)".  That way you aren't leaving orphan questions all over the place.   It may end up coming here anyway...

Comment: @harper-reinstate-monica Well, over there they said they were going to close the question since it was suggested I should have posted it over here. I assume closing is not the same thing as moving.

Comment: *et voila* ......... https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/242204/what-is-the-correct-way-to-wire-three-way-switches-and-a-single-pole-switch .... better written question anyway.